# Make Div on right side fill out all available space

Tags: html, css

I want to create two divs beside each other, however I want the one on the left side to be 300px, and the right one to take up the remaining amount on the screen. How would that be possible? Thanks!

Comment: width:auto; But your content size will matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight-forward (and I would say correct) way is to use `display: table`:

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#left, #right {
    display: table-cell;
    color: white;
}
#left {
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
}
#right {
    background: red;
}

<section id="wrapper">
    <aside id="left">Left 300px</aside>
    <div id="right">Right the rest</div>
</section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YbLZE/1/

Try resizing the bottom right frame.

Updated with `HTML5` elements `section` and `aside`, which you should use if you have an `HTML5 doctype`. I have to remember to use those...

Comment: Using a CSS layout to display block elements as table-cells does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is the working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tnm62/

Explenation:
1. Place both elements in one container.
2. Position your left element absolute, set its width to 300px.
3. Set left margin to your right element to 300px.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to `float: left;` the left `div` that's `300px` wide, and then apply `overflow: hidden;` to your right `div`.  Here's the basic outline:

HTML:

```
<div class = "left">
    Glee is awesome!
</div>
<div class = "right">
    Glee is awesome!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And a little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/H3tqj/).

Comment: That will work, but it's also a (long-running) corruption of `float` due to problems with older browser functionality.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yep, I just wanted to mention another method for reference since you already suggested using CSS tables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something for newer browsers (not IE):

**CSS**:

```
#container {
    display: box;
}

#left {
    width: 400px;
}

#right {
    box-flex: 1;
}
```

​**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N5zhH/1/**

Comment: MDN seems to suggest using [the newer Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Flexbox) standard, that deviates from the (apparently older and abandoned?) `box-` CSS3 draft standard. I'm somewhat new (as in, NEW) to this whole thing, so I'll let the MDN link speak for itself (whatever it says...). If properly supported, though, that would seem the most "natural" way to handle this, moreso than `display: table`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be sufficient:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 300px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="margin-left: 300px;"></div>
</div>
```

- `overflow: hidden` will stretch the container div to accommodate the tallest child element
- `float: left` floats the element left (doh!)
- `width: 300px` and `margin-left: 300px` together assures that if the right column is taller than left it will not flow *below* the left floated div; it will maintain a 300x gap from the left edge of container div

Tip: change to `margin-left: 320px` to add a 20px gutter

Here is a nice little [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DWd5k/)

Comment: Sorry, but using float's is a hack. At least `table-cell` does exactly what it's meant to do display-wise; a hack designed to retrofit buggy IE6 behavior is the lesser approach, in my opinion. Flexbox (as Blender was more or less showing) is the only "right" way as far as it goes, and also in my opinion way overdue. I just imagine it will be awhile before it is fully adopted.

Comment: I still think table for tabular data, not for layouts. But you have every right to disagree.

Comment: That's the thing, though, using css has nothing to do with semantics. Using `table` tags is, yes, semantics, but for display, it makes more sense than a hack of a text layout property for manhandling blocks into place. `display: inline-block` and `Flexbox` will eventually supersede and obsolete both of these "techniques", though, the sooner the better.