# Page content layout issues

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Div on right side fill out all available space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333712/make-div-on-right-side-fill-out-all-available-space)

I'm designing a theme for a blog and I'm having some trouble trying to get a layout working. Here's an image of what I want.

[image: A blog's content's layout]
This diagram represents the individual posts and not the website itself, so it will be contained in a box of it's own, lets call it `.container`. Also the purple and green are in another box, let's call it `.content`. The other elements will be called by their color for now.

so here's more or less what the CSS looks like:

```
.container { 
    display:block;
    margin:0 25px;
}

.gray, .blue, .content {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}

.purple {
    display:inline-block;
    width:125px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.green {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

That's all there is at the moment. I tried `float` but that made no effect. What's happening is something like this.

[image]

Here's a few more things you should know:

- `.container`'s width is NOT set it is auto
- `.purple` and `.green` don't necessarily need to be the same size as long as `.green` doesn't go to that side.
- `.purple` CAN have a set height
- `.green` is where the meat is, that's where the actual post goes, keep that in mind.
- I don't think tables will help, the problem is inside `.content.`

Comment: Can you include which browsers you want to support?

Comment: Will this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333712/make-div-on-right-side-fill-out-all-available-space/12333767#12333767 ?

Comment: @360flow Michael
Sweet baby jesus, yes, thank you, put an answer and I'll select it :). I don't use tables often, I always thought cells were forced to be equal width, or maybe I'm thinking of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use answers in this post to get a solution:

[Make Div on right side fill out all available space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333712/make-div-on-right-side-fill-out-all-available-space/12333767)

I am recommending tables-directed one because it is most valid/working approach on almost every browser.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all of your sections are `<div>` elements. Use:

```
.container { 
    display:block;
    margin:0 25px;
}

.gray, .blue, .content {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}

.purple {
    float:left;
    width:125px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.green {
    float:left;
}
```

You may also need to add `<br clear="all" />` immediately after the green `div` and before the closing of the `content` div, and another one right after your `content` div.

Comment: I got one thing working by taking out `float:left` from purple and making `.green` and `.purple` `display:block`. But the problem is that `.green` is stil 100% width. I guess I can pull a `margin-left:125px` maneuver.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all is set in div you need to write like this:

```
.container { 
    display:block;
    margin:0 25px;
}

.gray, .blue, .content {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}

.purple {
    float:left;
    width:125px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.green {
    float:left;
    min-width: 125px;
}
```